# Create Surrogate Primary Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, composite-primary-key

Let's say I have table as follows:

```
FirstName   MiddleName  LastName    EmailAddress
John        Middle      Steward     some@thing.com
Alice       Wonder      Land        some@thing.com
Steve       Mac         Qwak        some@thing.com
Miss        Mon         Cherie      some@thing.com
Liz         Sea         Shell       some@thing.com
```

This is data source with employees. As you can see, there is no primary key. Is there any way how to enhance these data with some kind of surrogate primary key? Note this is data source. I assume it is not possible to create any primary key out of the data as any time one of the row / column change, this will also lead to change of the surrogate primary key. Correct? Or is there any way?

These data are meant to be loaded into DWH using SSIS. As there should be some Lookup transformation, I need to have primary key in the source data set.

Comment: The surrogate PK is just an artificial key, with no actual connection to real data. You can just use an identity int key as a surrogate PK.

Comment: Simple .. I just wondered whether there exists any other possibility.

Comment: If you are planning to update data in the DWH, you'll need a primary key which matches the source system.  Adding an identity column for the sake of having a primary key does not assist in updating the data itself.  Names change, what does the source system use to identify a unique record whether it is enforced by a constraint or not?

Comment: Is there an actual problem that you are trying to address?

Comment: As Mark says, a surrogate key is not the answer. You need to find out what information is required to identify an employee, AKA a business key / natural key. Typically that's probably an employee / payroll number of some kind. EmailAddress could conceivably be your key but that's not something we can see from your sample data.